# AutoCompleteTextView and SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, widget

I have managed to marry an `AutoCompleteTextView` to SQLite via a SCA. The problem I am having is that when I select an item from the list, the text that is populated in the text field looks like a hash string. It definitely isn't what I selected. My list to select from would be City, ST. But what is returned is `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@424d4448` or something similar based on what is picked.

```
final AutoCompleteTextView city_to_show = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actView);

String[] town = new String[] {"city"};  
int[] id = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

SimpleCursorAdapter actv = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city_cursor, town, id);

actv.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

city_to_show.setAdapter(actv);

actv.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like your doing something like `cursor.toString()` instead of `cursor.getString(column_index)`

Comment: No where in the method is a cursor.toString().  The ACTV list is populated from the SCA, but when an item in that list is selected, I get that string in the text field.  I don't even have to tell ACTV to .setText();.

Comment: Because it doesn't work like it does with an ArrayAdapter. Here read and learn http://www.mekya.com/2013/09/17/how-to-use-autocompletetextview-and-simplecursoradapter-together-in-android/

Comment: I added :   city_to_show.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {//OnItemSelectedListener()
       
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

Comment: That code allowed me to do a .setText();  and thus solved my problem.  Thank you for your time and effort.